# Algoritmo em C para cadastro, pesquisa e exclusão

Tags: c

Boa noite pessoas, tudo bem? Estou desenvolvendo este algoritmo e estou com umas dificuldades em excluir nomes que cadastrei, não tenho conhecimentos avançados em C, e não sei se o modo de como fiz o código está certo ou está 100% otimizado, porém está funcionando, aceito todo tipo de dica e instruções para estudo de algum determinado tema, obrigado.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <conio.h>

int choice,gen;
int i;
char nomes[25][25];
char name[50][50];
char voider;

int main(){



            void menu(void);


            for(int x = 0; x <= 25; x++)
            for(int j = 0; j < 1; j++)
            nomes[x][j]='-';

            menu();

return 0;

}


void menu(void){

    void cadastro(void);
    void pesquisa(void);


printf("\n/----------------------------------------------------------------------/");
printf("\n/----------------------------------------------------------------------/");
printf("\n/-----------------------G A T H E R E R V2.0 --------------------------/");
printf("\n/----------------------------------------------------------------------/");
printf("\n/----------------------------------------------------------------------/");
printf("\n\nPress enter to continue...");
gets(&voider);


    system("cls");

printf("\n/----------------------------------------------------------------------/");
printf("\n/-----------------------M A I N   M E N U -----------------------------/");
printf("\n/----------------------------------------------------------------------/");
printf("\n/----------------------------------------------------------------------/");
printf("\n/---1 - REGISTER PEOPLE ===============================================/");
printf("\n/---2 - SEARCH PEOPLE =================================================/");
printf("\n/---3 - SHOW REGISTER =================================================/");
printf("\n/---4 - EXCLUDE PEOPLE ================================================/");

printf("\n/----------------------------------------------------------------------/");
printf("\n/---Select a option----------------------------------------------------/\n");
scanf("%d",&choice);
fflush(stdin);

        switch (choice){

  case 1:

    system("cls");
    cadastro();
    break;

  case 2:

    system("cls");
    pesquisa();
    break;

  case 3:

    system("cls");
    imprimi();
    break;

  case 4:

    system("cls");
    excluir();
    break;

}
}
void cadastro(void){

int g;
g = 0;


    while(g == 0){
        for(int x = 0; x <= 25; x++)
            for(int j = 0; j < 25; j++)
                if(strcmp(&nomes[x][j], "-") == 0){
        printf("\n/----------------------------------------------------------------------/");
        printf("\n/---------------------------REGISTER PEOPLE----------------------------/");
        printf("\n/----------------------------------------------------------------------/");
        printf("\n/----------------------------------------------------------------------/");
        printf("\n/-----Enter a name or press 1 to leave to menu ------------------------/\n");
                    scanf("%s", &nomes[x]);
                    system("cls");
                    if(strcmp(&nomes[x], "1") == 0){
                        if(strcmp(&nomes[x], "1") == 0){
                            nomes[x][j] = '-';
                        }
                        menu();
                    }
                }

    }

}
void pesquisa(void){

  void menu(void);





  printf("\n/----------------------------------------------------------------------/");
  printf("\n/---------------------------SEARCH PEOPLE -----------------------------/");
  printf("\n/----------------------------------------------------------------------/");
  printf("\n/----------------------------------------------------------------------/");
  printf("\n/--------- Enter the name to search in database: ----------------------/\n");
  fflush(stdin);
  gets(name);


  for(i = 0; i<= 25 ;i++){



  if(strcmp(&nomes[i],name[0]) == 0){




system("cls");

    printf("\n/----------------------------------------------------------------------/");
    printf("\n/---------------------------SEARCH PEOPLE -----------------------------/");
    printf("\n/----------------------------------------------------------------------/");
    printf("\n/----------------------------------------------------------------------/");
    printf("\n/---------The following name has been found: %s                         ",nomes[i]);

}
  }

  printf("\n/----------------------------------------------------------------------/");
  printf("\n/----------------------------------------------------------------------/");
  printf("\n/---1 -SEARCH AGAIN ===================================================/");
  printf("\n/---2 -GOTO MENU ======================================================/\n");



scanf("%d",&gen);

if(gen == 1){
    system("cls");
    pesquisa();
}
if(gen == 2){
    system("cls");
    menu();

}





}
void imprimi(void){

        printf("\n/----------------------------------------------------------------------/");
        printf("\n/---------------------------REGISTER LIST------------------------------/");
        printf("\n/----------------------------------------------------------------------/");
        printf("\n/----------------------------------------------------------------------/");
for(i = 0;i <=25;i++){

    printf("\nNome encontrado: %s",nomes[i]);


}

printf("\n1 - GOTO MENU\n");
scanf("%d",&choice);


if(choice == 1);

menu();

}
void excluir(void){

        printf("\n/----------------------------------------------------------------------/");
        printf("\n/---------------------------EXCLUDE PEOPLE-----------------------------/");
        printf("\n/----------------------------------------------------------------------/");
        printf("\n/----------------------------------------------------------------------/");
        printf("\n/----Enter a name to exclude:                                           \n");
        fflush(stdin);
        gets(name);

// Aqui eu insiro a comparação que irá trocar o "name" por um "-", simbolizando vazio quando eu entrar no menu "register list".



    system("cls");

    printf("\n/----------------------------------------------------------------------/");
    printf("\n/---------------------------EXCLUDE PEOPLE ----------------------------/");
    printf("\n/----------------------------------------------------------------------/");
    printf("\n/----------------------------------------------------------------------/");
    printf("\n/---------The following name has been excluded:                        ");




  printf("\n/----------------------------------------------------------------------/");
  printf("\n/----------------------------------------------------------------------/");
  printf("\n/---1 -EXCLUDE AGAIN ==================================================/");
  printf("\n/---2 -GOTO MENU ======================================================/\n");

    scanf("%d",&gen);

    if(gen == 1){
    system("cls");
    excluir();
    }
    if(gen == 2){
    system("cls");
    menu();
    }

    }
```

Dentro da função "excluir", estou com dificuldades em tentar comparar o "name" que recebo com os nomes que foram armazenados na array "nomes", eu consigo fazer com que a comparação "dê certo" porém, só consigo substituir apenas o primeiro caracter, ficando por exemplo "Lucas" para "-ucas".

Answer (score 1):

Oi tudo bem ? Espero que sim =).

Pelo que vi do seu codigo seria bom se voce refatorar ele, e mudar alguns lacos, alem de levar em conta o OS que esta sendo executado.
Alguns explos:

ao inves de colocar:
   `system('cls')`, seria mais recomendado fazer no comeco do codigo algo assim:

```
#ifndef __UNIX__
  #define limpar() system("clear");
  #define pressEnter() getchar();
#else
  #define limpar() system('cls');
  #define pressEnter() getch();
#endif
```

Esse trecho de codigo vai ser interpretado e rodado em tempo de compilacao, Assim voce tem a garantia que ele vai funcionar com o OS corretamente.

---

Outro ponto que importante 'e que voce fez um laco beeem entranho para voltar no menu e em outras partes do codigo, te recomendo fazer algo mais neese estilo:

```
while(choice!=5){ switch(choice)....}
```

Pois quando se chama uma funcao, o programa 'para', execulta aquela funcao em expecifico depois volta novamente para onde ele estava, e continua ate final da execucao, eu fiz um pequeno exemplo usando default(Quando o valor selecionado nao 'e nenhum dos case)

ps: Vou colocar no final e comentar

---

Outra coisa, variaveis globais, tente nao usalas, sei que 'e tentador mas nao as crie dentro da funcao e passe como parametro e\ou retorno. Declare uma struct(fora da main como se fosse global), depois faca um array, e depois mexa com ele.

---

E finalmente o strcmp(), ele compara duas string, entao basta passar sem medo e nao compara um char com string, umas das caracteristica das string em C 'e que elas sempre terminam em '\0', entao se voce procurar esse elemento voce pode ter certeza que chegou no final, mas se nao tiver ? Entao o programa provavelmente vai percorrer sua memoria ou ate chegar no final dela ou ate interpretar algo que ele considere '\0'.

exemplo:

```
   char str[10]="coisas";
   char str2[11]="treco";
   int result = strcmp(str,str2);

   o strcmp vai retornar certos parametros para cada situacao
```

---

Codigo exemplo:

```
#define TAMANHO 50 // Isso facilita em caso queira mudar o tamanho do vetor
#define TAMANHO_NOME 100

  struct pessoa
  {
       char nome[TAMANHO_NOME];
  };

   void adiciona(struct pessoa* lista_p,int tamanho)
   {
            // te recomendo fazer de forma dinamica 

   }

  void deleta(struct pessoa* lista_p,int tamanho)
  {
            usando o strcmp 
            e caso alocou dinamicamente use free();

   }

   int main()
   {
       int a=0;

  struct pessoa* lista_p[TAMANHO]; //Crio um array de ponteiro do tipo              struch pessoa
   //Lembrando que ele vai de lista_p[0] ate lista_p[49] 

  while(a!=3)
  {
    printf("Aperte 1 para adicionar");
    printf("Aperte 2 para deletar");
    printf("Aperte 3 para sair");
    scanf("%d", &a);

    switch(a){


        case 1:
            adiciona(*lista_p,TAMANHO); // Em c a menos que coloque uma condicao de parada no ultimo elemento, tem que se passar o numero de elementos
            break;

        case 2:

            deleta(*lista_p, TAMANHO);
            break;

        default:
            printf("Aperte uma das opcoes\n");
            break;
      }

  }
  return 0;
```

}

**E PESQUISE SOBRE PONTEIROS, SAO MUITO IMPORTANTES EM C!!!!!**

Cara acho que 'e isso deculpa a falta de acentucao, mas meu PC ta em ingles e estou com prequica de mudar...=P

referencia:

> https://www.ime.usp.br/~pf/algoritmos/aulas/stru.html
>
> http://blog.lucaspolo.com.br/2010/07/lendo-string-com-espacos-na-funcao.html
>
> https://www.ime.usp.br/~pf/algoritmos/aulas/pont.html
>
> https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/cpp/preprocessor/preprocessor-directives?view=vs-2019
>
> https://www.ime.usp.br/~pf/algoritmos/aulas/aloca.html